# Stripe API trial_end 10 seconds from now, environment independent

Tags: node.js, unix, stripe-payments, momentjs, stripe.net

I'm testing failing recurrent payments with Stripe Api.

To make recurrent payment fail soon after subscription creation, subscription itself should have trial period and trial_end on customer creation should be some time soon or string 'now'.

It I pass string 'now', card is charged right on Stripe.customers.create(), making it fail that isn't my objective.

Instead, I tried to pass current unix timestamp +10 seconds, but it seems that machine clock is set earlier on couple minutes that Stripe clock.

As a result, I get trial_end 1454753552 and trial_start 1454753109 that isn't 10 but 443 seconds.

Is there any other way to make test environment independent than changing system clock?

I'm using `moment().unix() + 10` to get current unix time + 10 secs and nodejs.

Comment: Hm, you *want* to keep the wrong system clock?

Comment: Actually no, I just changed it and have my 1454754618 - 1454754609 = ~10 seconds. I'm concerned about auto tests on remote machines. If one possible machine (or other developer machine) will have wrong clock, it will be very subtle and hard to debug issue. So it is the real reason I want to make it environment independent if possible.

Comment: Well there is https://www.npmjs.com/package/ntp-client, maybe that is the way to go?

Comment: Currently looks like an overkill for me but I'll remember this solution.
I was wondering if Stripe have something like 'now+10' built-in.

Comment: Well it's not exactly hard to use. Maybe overkill is not the right word. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone in the future. Stripe has now introduced "Test Clocks" to help with this kind of situation. You can set a simulation environment at a specific time while continuously advancing the clock to create scenarios. You can learn more about it [here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/testing/test-clocks)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there's a clean way to do this here. What I'd do is create the customer before that call and look at the `created` [property](https://stripe.com/docs/api#customer_object-created) on the [Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#customer_object) object. This tells you the clock that Stripe's servers are using. You can then quickly calculate the offset with your own clock and guess the correct timestamp to put in `trial_end` to create a trial period that ends in 10 seconds.

I'd also recommend against the 10 seconds part because even with the clocks in perfect sync, if your call is a bit too slow for that specific request the trial would end immediately and prevent you from testing what you're looking for. I personally use a 60 seconds delay to decrease the risk.